# combine each item from one list with each item of another in r

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to combine two vectors of sequential numbers in order to produce a matrix from which i can plot a grid. specifically my vectors contain longitude and latitude data respectively, but for simplicity sake, lets say i have:
    
    `matrix(seq(1, 3, 1))
         [,1]
    [1,]    1
    [2,]    2
    [3,]    3`

and

    `matrix(seq(1, 3, 1))
         [,1]
    [1,]    1
    [2,]    2
    [3,]    3`

and all i want is: 

          `[,1] [,2]
     [1,]    1    1
     [2,]    1    2
     [3,]    1    3
     [4,]    2    1
     [5,]    2    2
     [6,]    2    3
     [7,]    3    1
     [8,]    3    2
     [9,]    3    3`
(the above is fake and not actually from R) I've tried using a nested for loop to no avail. This seems way too simple to be giving me such trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for `expand.grid()`

```
a <- 1:3
b <- 1:3

expand.grid(a=a,b=b)
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 1
# 3 3 1
# 4 1 2
# 5 2 2
# 6 3 2
# 7 1 3
# 8 2 3
# 9 3 3

## Or perhaps, if order matters to you
rev(expand.grid(b=b,a=a))
#   a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 1 2
# 3 1 3
# 4 2 1
# 5 2 2
# 6 2 3
# 7 3 1
# 8 3 2
# 9 3 3
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. how is this functionally different from merge? which also worked well. can't believe i forgot that one.

Comment: Not really sure what *all* differences there are, as I've always used `expand.grid()` for this. One difference that comes immediately to mind is that `expand.grid()` can take an arbitrary number of data arguments where `merge` needs exactly two; you can do `expand.grid(a=a,b=b,c=c,d=d)`, but `merge(a,b,c,d,by=NULL)` won't work (though you could presumably do `merge(a, merge(b, merge(c,d, by=NULL), by=NULL), by=NULL)` or some such). But really, `expand.grid()` is the purpose-built tool for doing just this kind of operation, and it works fine, so I'm happy to stick with it.

Comment: @user3273131 one difference is that `exapand.grid` can't handle data.frames. In this case, with only two vectors, both behave similarly. If you want the cartesian product of pure vectors, `expand.grid` seem more appropriate, but it seems to me that if what you really want is the cartesian product of two data.frames, merge (or other equivalents like SQL commands) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `merge`:

```
m1 <- 1:3
m2 <- 1:3
merge(m1, m2, by=NULL)
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 1
3 3 1
4 1 2
5 2 2
6 3 2
7 1 3
8 2 3
9 3 3
```

The advantage of using `merge` is that if you have a `data.frame` instead of vectors, it can easily deal with it:

```
m1<- data.frame(x=1:3, a=rnorm(3))
m2 <- data.frame(y=1:3, b=rnorm(3))
merge(m1, m2, by=NULL)
  x          a y          b
1 1 -0.6827197 1 -0.2046336
2 2 -1.5920405 1 -0.2046336
3 3  1.7696125 1 -0.2046336
4 1 -0.6827197 2  0.1738251
5 2 -1.5920405 2  0.1738251
6 3  1.7696125 2  0.1738251
7 1 -0.6827197 3  0.5166421
8 2 -1.5920405 3  0.5166421
9 3  1.7696125 3  0.5166421
```